# Recommendations to Develop an iOS Game

Tags: ios

I have never developed an iOS game and I want to get that a basic character (a circle like head and five lines as arms, trunk and legs) walks over a line (it has to recognize the line), falling down when the line ends and without allowing user interaction. Is there a tutorial to do this? Should I use just Objective-C or must I use any other technology like Cocos2D?

Thanks for reading.

**Edited:**

All the action occurs in 2D and on a single screen. I think that I need an animation and to check collisions to know if the character must keep walking or fall down.

Comment: I already have the animation and I just have to get that the animation walks over a line (like in Trace but without user allowing interaction). To make the animation is really simple (I am just using Objective-C with an array of images). Perhaps I had not explained me well. Is it really so difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on in that scenario you describe:

1. Animated rendering
2. Scene management (scene graphs)
3. Inverse kinematics
4. Collision detection

I doubt you'll find a single simple tutorial that covers all this. You'll probably need to study each of these areas separately.

Since Objective-C is just a programming language, you will definitely need something more. If it's 2D, Cocos2D will certainly do the job, but for the amount of rendering activity you describe, it may be overkill. CoreGraphics will probably suffice.

Comment: Like I have edited, I do not need scene management because all the action occurs in 2D and on a single screen and I think that I have to check the collisions to know if the character can keep walking or must fall down (I do not know what is inverse kinematics). Do you know if exists a tutorial covering this simple example?